# Map/Merge data from a flat array into the rows of a 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mapping, array-merge, indexed

I want to add the values of array b to array a:

```
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];
$b = [3, 6, 9];
```

Result should be:

```
$result = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];
```

I am trying this (and lots of other stuff) but don't get it.

```
foreach ($a as $el) {
    $i = 0; 
    $el[] = $b[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not hard.

```
<?php
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];
$b = [3, 6, 9];
for($i = 0; $i < count($b);$i++) {
    array_push($a[$i],$b[$i]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here we are using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to achieve desired output. Hope this will be helpful.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/833528)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];
$b = [3, 6, 9];

array_walk($a,function(&$value,$key) use($b){
    array_push($value, $b[$key]);
});
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Your solution should be faster than mine.

Comment: I am unsure why this is voted up more than the `for loop` solution. This is alot more complicated - even using references. I guess because it looks more fancy?

Comment: @Xatenev See i gave an alternative approach to achieve desired output that's it.  I myself upvoted `for-loop` approach.

Comment: @Xatenev isn't this a faster solution than mine? `array_walk` should work faster. Of course, if an array is only as small as this one there is no difference. The second upvote is from me.

Comment: @SahilGulati Sure I upvoted your answer aswell - I was just confused because the `for loop` is definetly a better solution in this case because its a lot more readable, and I'd definetly recommend it to OP

Comment: @Danielius Dunno that is super-microoptimization that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Xatenev Friend.. I usually try to answer a question in a different approach than others, so that OP can have no. of options to pick from and he can learn different things from different approaches, yes you are right `for-loop` can also be good. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This should be as simple as:

```
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];          
$b = [3, 6, 9];
foreach($a as $key => &$arr){
    $arr[] = $b[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];
$b = [3, 6, 9];
$result = $a;
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if(!empty($b[$key])) {
        array_push($result[$key], $b[$key]);
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clever one-liner that no one else thought of:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56cf390b143cda69526312b5d61afbe5e6576ba0))

```
$a = [[1, 2],[4, 5],[7, 8]];          
$b = [3, 6, 9];

var_export(array_map('array_merge',$a,array_chunk($b,1)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 6,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 7,
    1 => 8,
    2 => 9,
  ),
)
```

This approach splits `$b` into the same structure as `$a`, then it is simple to merge them together.

If your input arrays are relatively small, a `foreach()` is probably the best choice.  As your input array grows in size, I believe you will find that my approach will have increasing performance benefits over `foreach()` (though I'll be honest I am basing this on other similar answers I have provided and I haven't actually benchmarked this case).